# Using Redux Toolkit to change the value of a component from outside the component?

Tags: reactjs

Sorry if this is obvious, but I've spent all day looking for an answer and can't seem to figure it out.

I removed some irrelevant code, but I have a store that looks like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import topScreenTextReducer from './uiSlice'

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        topScreenText: topScreenTextReducer
    },
})
```

The uiSlice file looks like this.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
    value: 'some text',
}

export const uiSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'topScreenText',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateTopScreenText: (state, action) => {
            state.value = action.payload
        },
    },
})

export const { updateTopScreenText } = uiSlice.actions

export default uiSlice.reducer
```

Then I have a "TopScreen" component that looks like this.

```
const TopScreen = () => {
    let topScreenText = getTopScreenText()
    return (
            <StyledTopScreenText>
                {topScreenText}
            </StyledTopScreenText>
    );
}

export default TopScreen;
```

My question is, how can I change the "topScreenText" from a different non-component file? For example if I have a "startQuiz" file that I want to use to adjust some of my UI components, I can't call useDispatch because it's outside of a component.

I've seen people asking similar questions on Reddit and other platforms, and either the question goes unanswered or the response is vague. I really struggle to make things work without examples to reference and change for my purposes.

Could someone help me out with how I could accomplish this? I've heard some people say to use connect, but again I can't find an example of what the syntax is supposed to look like.

And apparently Dan Abramov suggests against using connect to do this, though I'm not sure exactly why.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: "non-component file", can it be a hook?

Comment: It can be anything as long as it's not in a component, and I can export/import it as needed from other files. I just want to be able to call "updateTopScreenText" or something similar from other parts of my code. Thanks for responding @JacobSmit

Comment: If it can be a hook, you should have no problem using `useDispatch` and other hooks within it. If it is fully disconnected from React then you can directly access the store created with `createStore` this object should contain `getState`, `subscribe`, `dispatch` and `replaceReducer` functions that you can use to directly interact with redux. Redux was created for framework agnostic state management and is fully functional without react.